# Erro em metodo Get em uma collection

Tags: java, xml, getters-setters

Estou necessitando usar *XML* em um trabalho da universidade e tive problemas com um método *Get* que tive que implementar em uma *Collection*.

Depois de um tempo acabei dando uma olhada em alguns sites para fazer isso e encontrei o seguinte [tutorial](http://www.mballem.com/post/manipulando-arquivo-xml-parte-i-api-nativa/?i=1), nele tem uma classe *Contato* como segue abaixo com o campo telefones, e é dado uma instrução para criar um método *Get* para ela, eu o criei e a estrutura ficou resumidamente assim:

```
public class Contato {
     private Collection telefones = new ArrayList();
     public Collection getTelefones() {
         return telefones;
     }
}
```

Porém no trecho de código abaixo obtive um erro:

> ---Alterar tipo de fone para Object---

```
for (Telefone fone : contato.getTelefones()) {
    tagFone = doc.createElement("Telefone");

    idFone = doc.createElement("id");
    dddFone = doc.createElement("ddd");
    numeroFone = doc.createElement("numero");
    //Insere os valores de telefones nas tags referentes
    idFone.setTextContent(String.valueOf(fone.getId()));
    dddFone.setTextContent(String.valueOf(fone.getDdd()));
    numeroFone.setTextContent(String.valueOf(fone.getNumero()));
    //Insere as tags Telefone na tag Telefone
    tagFone.appendChild(idFone);
    tagFone.appendChild(dddFone);
    tagFone.appendChild(numeroFone);
    //Insere a tag Telefone na tag pai Telefones
    tagFones.appendChild(tagFone);
}
```

Tentei algo diferente mas não consegui solucionar. Creio que seja no metodo Get que eu mesmo implementei, e se a comunidade tiver como me ajudar ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie a Collection informando o tipo que vai ser retornado o objeto telefone sem solicitar a conversão.

`public Collection getTelefones() {
    return telefones;
}`